# pymysql: one try except can't catch multi-sql errors

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, pymysql

**UPDATE**

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='user',password='password',db='mydb',charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
    query = 'select * from test where id = 1;abcd'
    cur.execute(query)
    res = cur.fetchone()
    print(res)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    query = 'select * from test where id = 2;'
    cur.execute(query)
    res = cur.fetchone()
    print(res)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The code makes the result as below:

```
{'name': '', 'score': 1.1, 'id': 1}
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'abcd' at line 1")
```

The first line `{'name': '', 'score': 1.1, 'id': 1}` comes from the first query before `;` in the first `try...except...`. And then the error message comes from the second `try...except...` but it comes from the sql query `abcd`, which means that the `cur.execute(query)` in the second `try...except...` produces the exception because of `abcd` and `select * from test where id = 2;` isn't executed.

So how can I ignore the `abcd` and make the second query execute as expected?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I'm building a web server with python. I use MySQL as the database and the pymysql as the interface of the database.

Now I get an issue:
When some sql query makes an error because of a `;`, the program will be blocked even if I've used `try...except...`. Here is an example:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='user',password='password',db='mydb',charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
    query = 'select * from test where id = 1;abcd'  <--- exception!
    cur.execute(query)
    res = cur.fetchone()
    print(res)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

query = 'select * from test where id = 2;'
cur.execute(query)
res = cur.fetchone()
print(res)
```

As you see, the first `query` is illegal because of the part `;abcd`. So it will produce an error. However, the `try...except...` can not catch this exception because I find that the `print(e)` isn't executed. Here is the messages that I get:

```
{'score': 1.1, 'name': '', 'id': 1}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_mysql.py", line 23, in <module>
    cur.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 161, in execute
    while self.nextset():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 103, in nextset
    return self._nextset(False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 98, in _nextset
    conn.next_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 860, in next_result
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1057, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1340, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1014, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
the right syntax to use near 'abcd' at line 1")
```

I can't understand why the error can not be caught by `try...except...`. Moreover, it seems that the query which produces the error is `abcd`, instead of `select * from test where id = 1;abcd`. If I'm right, I think the `;` make this query into two queries.

Also, if I remove the `;`, which means that the first query becomes `query = 'select * from test where id = 1abcd'`, the `try...except...` could catch the error so the second query can be executed as expected.

So my question is: why the `try...except...` can't catch the error? What could I do to handle all of sql errors so that the program won't be blocked?

Comment: `File "db_mysql.py", line 23` — the exception seems to be from a different script.

Comment: @phd  I don't understand. The python script is just `db_mysql.py`.

Comment: Then you've omitted shebang line and a few lines after it, I suspect. And the error is not inside try/except block — it's an exception from line 23 that's outside of try/except.

Comment: @phd   ah ha. You are right! So `abcd` is bound on the second `cur.execute`? Let me check it...

Comment: @phd    I've reedited my question.

Comment: Of course `;` splits the query in two — it's standard SQL feature. As for the problem — it seems MySQL server (or may be it's PyMySQL client but I doubt it) collects incomplete queries so your second query becomes 'abcd select…' and it's where the server chokes.

Comment: @phd  Yes, you are right. So I'm thinking if I could do something like `cur.clear()` to clear all queries. If I can't, I think there is only one way to do: analysis the query, if there is `;`, execute `cur.execute` more than one time...

Comment: It'd be hard to just search for ';' because it could be inside a string: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE test='foo;bar'". You'd need a full-blown SQL parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is: why the try...except... can't catch the error? What
>   could I do to handle all of sql errors so that the program won't be
>   blocked?

Maybe with the good exception name?

```
try:
    …
except pymysql.err.ProgrammingError as except_detail:
        print("pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: «{}»".format(except_detail))
```

See all exceptions type in `help(pymysql.err)` or on [PyMySQL's Github](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/err.py)